# insert/update mysql column based on existing data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm updating an existing table by adding data into an existing column.

I have already have an output of the data to be inserted, but due to the amount of records, i'm looking for the best way to insert this into my table without having to manually write to each line of sql.

Here's my sql (partial) i want to insert into

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_user_variables_dobRE` (`user_id`, `value`) VALUES
(150, '1959-11-02'),
(151, '1948-04-20'),
(152, '1961-06-18'),
```

And this is the table i want to insert it into

```
id         | 7
username   | guestinvite
password   | BLANK
forname    | forname
surname    | surname
email      | guestinvite@test.com
address_id | 286
type_id    | 4
dob        | 0000-00-00
plusGuest  | 0
update     | 2016-02-16 11:54:36
created    | 2016-04-04 17:03:12
```

So i want to insert the second item into the 'dob' column where first item = id

Is there anyway to do this programmatically or do i have to write WHERE & OR statements for every line?

Comment: not possible. `insert` creates NEW records. if you want to target an already-existing record, you have to `update`. You **MAY** be able to use an `insert ... on duplicate key update`-type thing, but since you've provided no details about the table definition, that's not a sure thing.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB - I thought it would be an update, but hope there would be some kind of block update command i hadn't heard of before

Comment: nope. the multi-values syntax is a mysql extension specific for `insert`. there's no equivalent for update queries.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @MarcB - i better get going with my find and replace then, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You tagged both MySql AND sql-server in your post. The following is assuming you're using SQL Server, but the idea would remain the same in MySQL (just different syntax)...**

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you want to do an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`, being that you're modifying existing rows.

You said that you have an output of the data to be inserted - Insert this into a TEMP table and JOIN it to the table you'd like to update where the id's match.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Transaction1]  -- Do large updates as transactions to avoid data loss

CREATE TABLE #temp ( -- Create temp table
    [user_id] int,
    [dob] nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
   -- YOUR SELECT GOES HERE
   SELECT my_id as [user_id], my_dob as [dob]


UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.dob = t.dob
FROM tbl_user_variables_dobRE my_table
INNER JOIN #temp t ON t.user_id = my_table.id

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**If your data looks good, commit the transaction:** (Don't dwell too long, transactions lock table data!)

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION [Transaction1]
```

**Otherwise:**

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Transaction1]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer (i was referring to MySQL fyi - my mistake to the miss tag). Both the answers solved the problem and did the update in 5 minutes rather than 2 hours

Comment: Awesome stuff! Tyler's answer is much more in-depth than mine - Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way I can think of doing this is creating a temporary table with the new data that you want to add (you could possibly bulk import it all from say, a CSV file).

The temporary table will just need a couple of columns - one with `user_id` and the other one `dob` - you'll be getting rid of it after anyway.

You could then do something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_user_variables_dobRE a
  JOIN tmp_table b
    ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id )
   SET a.dob = b.dob
```

Once you've done that you can `DROP` your temporary table and be good to go - good luck!

**Important**

Be super-careful when updating data - it's so easy to mess up your data by forgetting to add a clause. If possible, do this with some test data before trying it with the real production data.